# Extjs4 Ext.selection.CheckboxModel with Ext.grid.property.Grid

Tags: extjs, grid, selectionmodel

First of all, I am using Extjs 4.1.

I have a grid with property grid and I want to add a column of checkbox into the grid. The property grid code is as follows:

```
    var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.property.Grid', {
        tbars:[],
        selModel: Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel',{mode: 'MULTI'}),
        columnLines: true,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

        source: {
            "grouping": false,
            "autoFitColumns": true,
            "productionQuality": false,
            "created": Ext.Date.parse('10/15/2006', 'm/d/Y'),

        }
    });
```

However the checkbox selection model does not show up in the grid.

anyone can point me to the correct direction or property grid does not work with checkbox ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the `selModel` property is documented in `Ext.grid.property.Grid`, this is only because `Ext.grid.property.Grid` extends `Ext.grid.Panel`. The problem is that this type of grid only has a fixed `selModel` and namely of type `cellmodel`. You can see its behaviour by clicking on a property (the property editor gets the focus and e.g a date proeprty shows a date picker). The `cellmodel` selModel is hard coded in the source code in the `initComponent()` method, so if you want to change that, you should write your own subclass in which you overwrite that.